# How to check Android devices for WiFi or hotspot support

Tags: android, wifi, hotspot, tethering

Does anyone know how an app may check whether a device supports WiFi mobile hotspot/WiFi tethering? For example, my Android phone has this functionality and you can tether the 3G connection, while my newer android tablet does not support it.

To complicate things further, I actually have another tablet, with only WiFi and no 3G that do support the portable hotspot mode.

Please observe that I am not asking how to enable the hotspot, just whether the device has support for it.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer from Google is that there is no API for checking this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no office APIs, but you can check one which I have publish on

https://github.com/mady4ever/android-testhotspot

For Doc

http://mady4ever.github.io/TestHotspotdoc